# Why the debugger shows one value and when returning number++ doesn't returns the correct number javascript

Tags: javascript

I was just testing this on javascript and noticed that each time I return a variable with a ++, it didn't return the new number. I know the ++ is added after, but shouldn't be added before returning it. When I debugged it, is showing the correct number, but when returning it doesn't. Does the interpreter executes this line after the return? If it's like that why the debugger shows the correct value?

This function returns the correct number without the ++. It returns 10.

```
function test(){
  var counter=0;
  for(i=0;i<10;i++){
    counter++;
  }
  return counter;
}
```

This other function, I thought it should return 11, but it doesn't it returns 10.

```
function test1(){
  var counter=0;
  for(i=0;i<10;i++){
    counter++;
  }
  return counter++;
}
```

[Demo](http://jsbin.com/xediya/1/edit) showing this example.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

`counter++` is a `post increment` operator. It first perform the operation with current value after that it increments the value.

you should youse `++counter` `pre increpent` operator.

Comment: Yes I got it, but why on the debugger is showing the correct number? And at the moment of returning it doesn't?

Comment: @Diego I think that's because after just return it would have incremented the value of `counter`.

Comment: that's actual funny and confusing how the debugger shows the result

Comment: @Diego may be but that's what `post incremtnt` works, after executing the `expression` immediately increment the value.

Answer (score 0):

```
function test1(){
  var counter=0;
  for(i=0;i<10;i++){
    counter++;
  }
  return ++counter;
}
```

By moving the `++` in front, it affects the variable before it's returned.

Answer (score 0):

++ increments the number *after* the line it's on executes. So if you check your counter variable afterwards, it will be 11, but at the time when you're returning it, it's 10. Use "++counter" if you want to increment before returning.